# Prove if $S \subseteq T \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, then $\operatorname{span}(S) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x \in S$. Then $ax \in \operatorname{span}(S)$. Since $S \subseteq T$, then $x \in T$ and $ax \in \operatorname{span}\{T\}.$

Would that make sense?

Comment: You need to also consider finite combinations of elements of $S$.

Comment: Should I start with $x, y \in S$ instead?

Comment: This exercise is trivial once you write down the definition of $span$. Just try it.

Comment: Let $S = \{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ be a set. Then $span(S) = \{\sum_{(i = 1)}^k (a_iv_i): a \in \mathbb R\}$?

Comment: I don't know how the given definition changes if $S$ is uncountable. Can you tell me, please?

Comment: If $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is of any cardinality, then $\operatorname{span}(S) = \{ \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i \mid v_i \in S,\ \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R} \textrm{ for } 1 \le i \le k\}$.

Comment: @ Heterbrij, I don't get it. Is your definition different from the one given in my book for finite sets because someone said the definition of span is different for sets of different cardinaities, but deleted their post?

Comment: You shouldn't start either with $x\in S$ or with $x,y\in S$, but rather with $x\in\operatorname{span} (S)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @hereinmygarage The difference lies in what you sum over. In your definition for a finite set $S$ you're summing over *all* the elements in $S$. In general, though, you sum over only *finitely many* elements. This may be more clear with definition equivalent to Hetebrij's:
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{span}(S) = \Big\{\sum_{v \in S} \lambda_v v &: v \in S, \lambda_v \in \Bbb{R}, \\ &\text{ and } \lambda_v \neq 0 \text{ for at most finitely many } v \in S \Big\} .
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If
$v\in\operatorname{span}S$, then
$$v=\sum_{x\in S}a_xx,$$
where all but finitely many $a_x=0$.

In other words, 
$$v=a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n$$
for some $x_1,\ldots x_n\in S$.

But, this implies
$$v=\sum_{x\in T}b_xx,$$
where 
$$b_x=\begin{cases}0, & x\ne x_k\quad\text{for some } 1\le k\le n\\
a_k,& x=x_k\end{cases}$$

Hence, $v\in\operatorname{span}T$ also.

Comment: Nice. If nonempty, finite $U, V \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, then $span(U) + span(V) \subseteq span(U \cup V).$  Let me try and prov it. Suppose $U = \{u_i: i \in \mathbb N\}$ and $V = \{v_i: i \in \mathbb N\}$. Then $span(U) + span(V) = \{\sum_{i = 1}^k(a_iu_i + b_iv_i)\}$. Since $U \cup V$ contains $u_i, v_i$, $span(U \cup V)$ contains the set of all $a_iu_i + b_iv_i$. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've edited the post to  include the case where $S$ and $T$ are infinite.

Comment: @ TonyK, the exercise in the title doesnt say anything about the cardinality of $S$, but the next one that I tried in the comments does. I think the author simply forgot to include it since the definition of span is given for finite sets.

Comment: @ Tim Raczkowski, can you check my other exercise in the comments?

Comment: @hereinmygarage You should create another post for a completely new question. :)

Comment: @ Tim Raczkowski, can you spell out the sum of all $b_xx$ as a linear combination because I am having hard time seeing that from the definition of $b_x$?